# same functions name in different pages

Tags: asp-classic, logic

I have some ASP pages and sometimes different pages have same name functions.
I don't get why those functions react randomly (not executing, error saying is already defined,etc.) if I only `<!-- #include -->` the one page the user requested. It shouldn't be giving me an error, I guess...
Can someone explain me this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds obvious but are you sure you only include the required function page once per page and that you haven't included a page which itself includes the function page declaring the variable?

Also check that the variable in question isn't declaired for some other purpose on the pages that are erroring.

(I only say this because it's something I often fall foul of)

Comment: I have one page (index.asp) that calls every other page with an if...elseif... condition.No other page beside this one calls other pages.It doesn't make sense, it's like if ASP checks all the pages and verifies that every function is unique. Weird.

Comment: ASP will check the the entire page and all includes (including embeded includes) regardless of `if this...` or `response.end` statments. So if you have multiple includes or declarations then you need to ensure that any **Dim**s only appear once and your functions include is only included once (no need to have hte page reprocessing includes if not required).

Comment: Ok i'll guess I'll have to deal with it. I've been renaming functions by name and putting 1 or 2 or 3 after the name (name1,name2,etc.).That sucks.Thanks anyways!

Comment: Yep, not great - just remember to be descriptive with your functions/declarations and that a function only needs to be included once (regardless of if's or deapth of include). Glad I could help :-)